# unlocking screen returns to login (lightdm)

Tags: screen, lightdm, lock, openbox

Unlocking the screen for an openbox session returns to the lightdm login screen. I want to not return to lightdm or allow to switch away from the current logged in user. Had this working in 16.04 but running into issues with 20.04.

Using xautolock, light-locker or gnome-screensaver returns to lightdm after unlocking.

edit: Login back via lgihtdm does resume the session at least.

Comment: Are there any .crash files in your /var/crash directory that match the time of a lock or unlock?

Comment: @user535733 no files in /var/crash. let me tail various logs in /var/log to see if something pops up